# Proper way of Extending TypeScript interface properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
export interface IDDMenuItem {
  [key: string]: object extends { disabled:boolean,label:string, type:string}
}
```

This way not seems to be legit -

Getting these errors:

```
Return type of index signature from exported interface has or is using private name ''.
Return type of index signature from exported interface has or is using private name ''.
'?' expected.
```

Looking for the proper way of extending properties.

Comment: Can you please provide an expected output as, at least I am, not 100% sure I know what you want to do? Should your `object` have at least those three properties or the whole interface `IDDMenuItem` should at least have those three properties?

Comment: Yes, it should have at least these 3 props. @Mushroomator

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you can do something like this:

```
export interface IItem {
  disabled: boolean;
  label: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface IDDMenu {
  [key: string]: IItem;
}
```